# Buttons in RelativeLayout fill screen width

Tags: android, button, width, android-relativelayout

[image]

As you can see above, I have four rows of `Buttons` in a `RelativeLayout`. How can I have the `Buttons` cover the screen width evenly?

I've tried all sorts of things but nothing has worked: I tried setting the `RelativeLayout` width to `match_parent` and making all the `Button's` `layout_width` = `fill_parent` and all sorts of things like that.

Any ideas?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Game" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id = "@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button0"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

...
...
...

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button13"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button14"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to have four vertical Linear layouts which each contain their buttons in a horizontal Linear Layout. Make sure that all the buttons width is `fill_parent`

Then set the weight attribute to each of the made the LinearLayouts width = match_parent and set the Buttons layout_weight = "1"made the LinearLayouts width = match_parent and set the Buttons layout_weight = "1" to 1 like this:

`android:layout_weight = "1"`

Make sure the Linear layouts width are also set to `match_parent`

Basically this adds up the weights and divides the screen width into between the buttons.

The solution to your problem is in weights.

Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

P.S. If this answers your question please mark this as the correct answer

Comment: I did something similar but the layout is not correct. I have a vertical LinearLayout with 4 horizontal LinearLayouts inside it. And I made each horizontal LinearLayout layout_weight="1" and all are set to fill_parent. But the first button in each row takes up the entire screen. Are you sure I am supposed to set the Layouts weight to 1 or do I set the buttons weight to 1?

Comment: I fixed it. basically made the LinearLayouts width = match_parent and set the Buttons layout_weight = "1" --- not the linearLayouts! So if you edit your post I'll mark yours as the correct answer. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Will edot it as soon as i get on computer

Answer (score 0):

You could get the screen dimensions and use them to decide the buttons size

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

and then use these sizes to determine the size of your buttons (each size would be the width divided by 4)

Fiddling around with this should get you where you want

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `LinearLayout` and `weight` property for a row? It could be something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Game" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id = "@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_row_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:tag="0"/>

</LinearLayout>

...
...
...

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_row_4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_row_3">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick" 
    android:tag="0"/>
</LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If it won't work, try to set buttons' `android:layout_width` property to `0dp`